# java.lang.IllegalStateException with @Async in method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a method that only calls a procedure in mysql. This is my code:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ClientService {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Async
    public void callFunction(Integer clientId) {

        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("myProcedureSql");
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("clientId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
        query.execute();
    }

}
```

I need it to run asynchronously, but when I put the @Async tag in the method it fails giving me the following error:

```
196536 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler  - Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void ar.com.lemondata.turnero.backend.service.PruebaService.procesarCSV()'.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

If I remove the @Async the code works perfectly

Comment: Have you annotated your application with `@EnableAsync`?

Comment: Yes, the @EnableAsync tag is set

Answer (score 0):

`@Async` will spawn a new thread (if threadpool is not configured) and for the same ,  It cannot inherit the parent Transaction. Because, Spring Transaction is per thread basis.

If you put `@Transactional` with relevant propagation value . This should solve your problem.

I won't recomend this way of Transaction Management unless it is super critical.

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-transaction